# Unable to install packages to R 3.2.2 using R Studio.

Tags: r

Recently I have been unable to install any packages into R 3.2.2 using R Studio and Windows 7, which has never been a problem before. I see the following warning messages (same messages for attempts to install other packages also):

```
> install.packages("forecast")
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated    abnormally'
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository <...omitted....>
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository <...omitted...>
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘forecast’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated  abnormally'
Warning in install.packages :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'
```

Following tips that I've read online, I've tried following
Tools--> Global Options-->Packages and changing the CRAN mirror (I had been using Global (CDN) - RStudio, but have tried to change to 0 Cloud, UC Berkeley, and Oregon State University). I have also tried using type="source" as an argument in the install.packages command. Before submitting this question, I uninstalled R and RStudio and reinstalled, yet still have the same problem. I have also verified that packages install properly on other lap top computers connected to the WiFi in my house. If anybody has any insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate hearing them.

Comment: Do you have any old proxy configurations defined on your computer?

Comment: Have you tried you install using RGui instead of RStudio?

Comment: @Dason, Trying to install using RGui does not seem to work either, with a different error message: Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this?